# Remove mathematical operator consecutive, at the beginning and end of string

Tags: regex, r

I have the following strings:

```
str1 = "+58*/-47+-2*"
str2 = "++*46+8+*7+2*1"
str3 = "-9*-"
```

I want the following outputs:

```
ostr1 = "58*47+2"
ostr2 = "46+8+7+2*1"
ostr3 = "9"
```

Eg rules are:

- mathematical operators are `+, - , /, *`
- when there is at least two consecutive mathematical operators in the string, take the first one.
- suppress all consecutive mathematical operators at the beginning or end of string.

So far I fill the third condition with:

```
gsub("(.*)[\\+|-|\\*|/]+$", "\\1", gsub("^[\\+|-|\\*|/]+(.*)", "\\1", str1))
```

Which seems not very elegant.. and I am stil struggling for the second condition:

```
gsub("([\\+|-|\\*|/]{1})[\\+|-|\\*|/]+", "\\1", str1)
```

Does not work.

Any suggestions are welcomed from `regex` killers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search by:

```
^[-+*/]+|[-+*/]+$|([-+*/])[-+*/]+
```

and replace by:

```
$1 or \\1
```

Code:

```
gsub("^[-+*/]+|[-+*/]+$|([-+*/])[-+*/]+", "\\1", str1)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT4fS8/1)

Comment: Insane, far more simple than my bad approach :)